# Check if a child component rendered any own child components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a list of components which have to fetch their own data and render childs based on the fetched data. How can I show a `FallbackComponent` as child of the top component if all of the child components (`ComponentA`s) don't have any own childs?

Example:

```js
ContainerComponent

    FallbackComponent // should only render if there is not a single ComponentB in any ComponentA

    FallbackComponent2 // Renders if there is no ComponentA

    // Below should only render if there is atleast one ComponentB
    ComponentA // fetches own data - to render some ComponentB
        ComponentB
        ComponentB
        ComponentB
    ComponentA // fetches own data - to render some ComponentB
        ComponentB
        ComponentB
    ComponentA // fetches own data - to render some ComponentB
        ComponentB
        ComponentB
        ComponentB
    ComponentA // fetches own data - to render some ComponentB
        ComponentB
        ComponentB
```

I already tried to listen for `childNodes` on ContainerComponent which counts the number of ComponentB's but according to React Doc this is not recommend and it also doesn't work because the data will update quite often. Also I tried to pass the number of each results from ComponentA up to the ContainerComponent to render the Fallback if `results === 0` but in this case the results length from one ComponentA overwrites the results length of another.

Comment: Is it possible to have the FallbackComponent in each ComponentA instead ?

Comment: You could use react-redux to let each `C_A` push its data to the store. `ContainerComponent` could then use a simple selector to check what kinda fallback it should show, if needed

Answer (score 1):

The way i see it is that your container should be aware when a componentA data is done being fetched & if it has rendered a component. Each ComponentA could have a props "onSuccess" From the container Component that will return the number of component rendered

ContainerComponent

```
const [components, setComponents] = [{cName: "", nbChildren: 0}]

onSuccess = (componentName, nbChildrenRendered) => {
newComponentList = new Set([...components, {cName: componentName, nbChildren: nbChildrenRendered}])
setComponents(newComponentList)
}

<ComponentA onSuccess={onSuccess} />
```

ComponentA :

```
const fetchData = () => {
/... Your implementation */
onSuccess("myComponent", data.structureYouLoopOnToRenderYourChildren.length)
}
```

Then its just a matter to check inside your `component` state if the nbOfChildren for a specific component is valid according to your criterias or not

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. I already tried something similar with a Map<"componentName", length> thing. Your approach with an array of objects is quite better BUT since there is a lot of data with a lot of liveupdates by websockets, it is possible that to state manipulations from two or more componentA's will happen at the same time. so in this case the sync list will get out of sync because one state change from one Component A will "overwrite" the others ComponentA change in that case.